# wordpress footer not in footer.php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, footer

I'm attempting to add to my church's website's footer, but the information in the footer is not pulling from the footer.php file.  I've spent all day going through various php and css files and I cannot find where this information is pulling from.  Would anyone be able to help me figure out from where this information is pulling?  Also, if it helps, I'm using the theme church, a child theme of the omega theme.

The site is:  https://cocsh.com/

Thank you in advance for any help you're able to provide!

Comment: login in admin > appearance > customize you will see the copyright text there

Comment: Nope.  There's no footer option there, I've already looked and tried there.

Answer (score 0):

admin > appearance > customize > footer "OR" this will be inside in theme option menu on left side of admin ... theme option > footer .

Comment: Nope.  it's not in either of those places, I've looked through all the customize options and there aren't any footer options there or within the theme settings.